# Small question for Chapter 5 in Peskin QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I'm reading Chapter 5 in Peskin QFT. And I'm confused in (5.94) and (4.84). In this Section, they want to evaluate cross section for Compton scattering in Center-of-Mass frame.
Initial electron has 4-vector momentum $p=(E,-\omega \hat{z})$, Initial photon has $k=(\omega, \omega \hat{z})$, where $\hat{z}$ is unit-vector along $z$-axis. And final electron and photon has $p'$ and $k=(\omega, \omega\sin \theta,0, \omega \cos \theta)$ respectively.
And they can obtain unpolarized invariant matrix element $\mathcal{M}$ by
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\rm spins}|\mathcal{M}|^2\simeq 2e^4\frac{E+\omega}{E+\omega \cos \theta}
\end{align}
where sum over spins contains the sum over polarization of photons and $e$ is electric charge which electron has. From this, by using (4.84), which give the connection between $\mathcal{M}$ and differential cross section $d\sigma/d\Omega$ in CM frame,
\begin{align}
(4.84)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)_{\rm CM}=\frac{1}{v_{AB}2E_A 2E_B}\frac{|\boldsymbol p_1|}{16\pi^2 E_{\rm cm}} |\mathcal{M}|^2
\end{align}
where $E_A$ and $E_B$ are energies which initial particle $A$ and $B$ has. In this case, $A$ is initial electron and $B$ is initial photon, then $E_A=E,\ E_B=\omega$. $E_{\rm cm}$ is initial total energy, thus we can get $E_{\rm cm}=E+\omega$. $|\boldsymbol p_1|$ is is the magnitude of the momentum of either of the initial particles $|\boldsymbol p_1|=\omega$. Thus we can get unpolarized-differential cross section
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)_{\rm CM}=\frac{1}{v_{AB}2E 2\omega}\frac{\omega}{16\pi^2 (E+\omega)} \left( \frac{1}{4}\sum_{\rm spins}|\mathcal{M}|^2\right)\\
=\frac{1}{v_{AB}2E 2\omega}\frac{\omega}{16\pi^2 (E+\omega)}\frac{2e^4(E+\omega)}{E+\omega \cos \theta}\\
\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\cos \theta}\right)_{\rm CM}=\frac{1}{v_{AB}2E 2\omega}\frac{\omega}{8\pi (E+\omega)}\frac{2e^4(E+\omega)}{E+\omega \cos \theta}
\end{align}
where I perform $d\phi$ integral and it gives $2\pi$ factor. However, Answer in Peskin QFT (5.94) is
\begin{align}
(5.94)\ \ \ \ \ \left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\cos \theta}\right)_{\rm CM}=\frac{1}{2\cdot 2E 2\omega}\frac{\omega}{8\pi (E+\omega)}\frac{2e^4(E+\omega)}{E+\omega \cos \theta}
\end{align}
This means $v_{AB}\equiv |v_A-v_B|$, the Velocity difference of incident particles is $2$. However, I'm having trouble getting this factor $2$. If you have done this calculation before or know how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Authors consider the condition $E>>m$, and for the relativistic particles there is a following general relationship about the velocity of particles: $v_i=p_i/E$. Then, one can conclude that $v_{AB}=|\mathbf{p_A}/E_A-\mathbf{p_B}/E_B| $. Finally, using the condition $E>>m$, you will relate $\omega$ and $E$. By using such relationship, you could reach the author’s result.

Comment: Siam, Thank you for your answer! I understood.